# file iteration failing

Tags: ruby, file

I'm trying to iterate each line of a file this way:

```
@dump_users=File.open("#{@tmp_dir}path_to_file.txt","r")
puts "about to open file #{@dump_users.path} with size #{@dump_users.readlines.size}"
puts "calling gets: #{@dump_users.gets}"
 while (user_line=@dump_users.gets) do
    arr=user_line.split("\t")
    puts "About to add user: #{arr.inspect}"
    query="INSERT INTO users VALUES (%s,\"%s\")" % [arr.at(0),arr.at(1).chop]
    puts "Added users: #{arr.inspect}"
    @db_3.execute(query)
 end
```

The first `puts` line prints the correct path and the file's line amount (362), then the second "calling gets" prints nothing, and the loop is actually never entered.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't use `inspect` to view the array after splitting. Instead use `join(' ')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with what you're doing. I'd write it like this untested code:

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.connect(@dsn)

path_to_file = File.join(@tmp_dir, "path_to_file.txt")
puts %Q[About to open "#{ path_to_file }"]
File.foreach(path_to_file) do |user_line|
  arr = user_line.split("\t")
  puts "Adding user: #{arr.join(' ') }"
  DB[:users].insert(fname: arr[0], lname: arr[1])
end
```

- Instead of using `open`, then never closing the file, use a block with Ruby's IO or File class methods to automatically `close` the file when the block exits. This preserves system resources.
- Instead of using `open` with a `readlines`, which is not scalable, iterate over the file line-by-line if you need to know how many entries there are. `foreach` is almost, if not as fast, as `readlines` and won't open your code up to consuming all space if the file you're processing turns out to be several hundred GB in size. For instance, you can do a simple pre-flight check of the file to see how many lines you need to read using:

  ```
  lines_in_file = 0
  File.foreach('file_to_read') { lines_in_file += 1 }
  puts "There are #{ lines_in_file } lines."
  ```
- If you need to see each line before inserting it, use something you're more in control of than `inspect`, such as a simple [String `format`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25) line:

  ```
  puts 'Adding user: %s %s' % [arr[0], arr[1]]
  ```

  `inspect` is useful for debugging, but not in production code so don't get into that habit.
- Don't insert values into a database query "insert" string. Never. Ever. That's a direct path to a SQL-injection attack if that file got compromised or comes from an unknown/unsecure source. Instead, at a minimum you should use placeholders. But, a better path is to use a good ORM, like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net), and let it handle generating the code needed to interface with your DBM. It's easier, and battle-tested.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `@dump_users.readlines`, you're advancing the location to the end of the file. Call `@dump_users.rewind` before iterating.

Answer (score 0):

`@dump_users.readlines.size` advances the file pointer to the end of the file. Try removing that line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the call to `readlines` and `gets`. `readlines` will advance the file pointer to end the of the file and `gets` then has nothing to read and returns nil:

```
@dump_users=File.open("#{@tmp_dir}path_to_file.txt","r")
# puts "about to open file #{@dump_users.path} with size #{@dump_users.readlines.size}"
# puts "calling gets: #{@dump_users.gets}"

while (user_line=@dump_users.gets) do
  arr=user_line.split("\t")
  puts "About to add user: #{arr.inspect}"
  query="INSERT INTO users VALUES (%s,\"%s\")" % [arr.at(0),arr.at(1).chop]
  puts "Added users: #{arr.inspect}"
  @db_3.execute(query)
end
```

Comment: running a test right now, thx for this! i wasnt aware of the internal work of gets and readlines